# Smart Refresher is not working on DefaultTabController and Slivers

Tags: flutter, dart, pull-to-refresh

Here I'm trying to add Smart Refresher on DefaultTabController and Silvers.

When I try to pull down, nothing happens on the page, there is no error in the terminal as well.

I can't able to understand whats the issue is, what am I doing wrong here.

```
Scaffold(
  body: SmartRefresher(
    header: const ClassicHeader(),
    footer: const ClassicFooter(),
    controller: refreshController,
    onRefresh: _onRefresh,
    onLoading: _onLoading,
    child: DefaultTabController(
      length: myTabs.length,
      child: NestedScrollView(  
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                color: Constants.surface,
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14, horizontal: 20),
                child: const Text("Header..."),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: const [
            CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Tab1(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            CustomScrollView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Tab2(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to put the smartrefresher in each of the tabs**

Comment: I need only Refresher on top of the page,rather than on each tab. On pull down, the data should be updated on both tabs.